# Asp.Net MVC Project Boilerplate with external auth

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

On my company there is a Java Auth Service i have to consume with my Asp.Net MVC project.

This is not a problem, but i have to create a Boilerplate Project which should be an Empty MVC project, with the Java Auth Service Module set it.

I want that when someone starts a new project (with the boilerplate i will create), has the Java Auth Service installed and working with each new page created.

Do you know how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You need to export your project/s as a template after you add what you need to the basic one.

Take a look at this *how to*:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx

Comment: But what i want to know is how can i use the mvc auth with an external provider... i mean, what should i do to mvc for check the authorization and authentication with a Java Web Service. I am sorry if i didn't explain very well at the article